# "nested choice" multinomial model

Tags: model, multinomial-distribution, choice-modeling

I would describe a model (and solve with the `stan` software) a process like this:

for i = 1...N consumers

1. the i-th consumer is allowed to choose an item out of 7. 6 items remain.
2. the same consumer chooses another item out of the 6 remaining items.

I collected the N pairs of choices and I would like to infer if there are some preferences.
The first step is a multinomial model. The second is a multinomial process conditioned by the first choice.
I really struggle to model the log probability function and code it in stan. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem cannot be solved as a multinomial but rather using [Fisher's noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution)